# tinymce setContent not working with erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, erb

In my web application I am using the tinymce editor to allow users to create html emails. I have included a feature where they can save a template to the database so they can use it for multiple emails and access it where ever they want. But when I am trying to load the content that is stored in the database, back into the editor, it just inserts the html string. I want it so the html is rendered so they can see the template like it was when they saved it.

I think the problem has something to do with ERB because when I pass in a normal string it works fine, but when I use ERB to use an instance variable it just sets the content to the html string, not correctly formatted. Here is my code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    ...
    oninit : "loadTemplate"
});

function loadTemplate() {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("<%= @template %>");
}
```

This would just put `<strong>Text Here</strong>` in the editor, but this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    ...
    oninit : "loadTemplate"
});

function loadTemplate() {
    template = "<strong>Text Here</strong>";
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(template);
}
```

works perfectly fine and puts **Text Here** in the editor. What is going on here that is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `@template` contains an HTML String, rails will automatically escape it. To prevent the escaping, try adding `raw`, like so:

```
<%= raw @template %>
```